# Typecasting of pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers

How integer pointer to char pointer conversion works?
I have a program that has integer value 320 and I'm typecasting into char*. It will show the output 64. I want to know how its works?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=320;
    char *p=(char*)&i;
    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not printing the contents of `i`, neither are you printing `p`. Instead you print the address of the variable `i`. And you use the wrong format specifier to print pointers (to print a pointer you should use `"%p"`, and the pointer must be casted to `void *`).

Comment: How to check the number fit in 8 bit or not?

Comment: Not clear why you have that pointer at all. A modern compiler with all recommended warnings enabled should warn about an unused variable. And read the man-page of `printf`. Which argument type does `%d` expect? What do you pass? The code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: This just has nothing to do with the type-cast, since you don't even use `p`. This is about *undefined behavior* since you have mismatching [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format specifier and argument.

Comment: As for if a value will fit in an 8-bit type? What is the *range* of valid value for an 8-bit type? Signed and unsigned?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think OP was responding to my (now deleted) comment where I asked if in their opinion 320 would fit in 8 bits.

Comment: sorry. Now i changed the code

Comment: It depends on the platform you use. Note that casting ot `char *` resp. accessing as `char` is a special case. Any answer **does not apply to other types**!

Comment: @Sourav Please remove the strict-aliasing tag. This question has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Another problem here is that the `char` type in C is useless for storing bytes of raw data, since it has implementation-defined signedness. Use `uint8_t` instead.

Comment: @user694733 any why would that be? I believe , without that tag, it creates a pitfall where the a next attempt to R&D lead to `short`, `long` etc.... So, I believe that would not be out of context here. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, on your little-endian system, let's assume `sizeof (int)` is 4.

Then the memory for `i` looks like:

```
   +--+-+-+-+
i: |64|1|0|0|
   +--+-+-+-+
```

This is because 320 is 0x00000140, i.e. 320 = 1 * 256 + 64.

So you set `p` to point at the first byte (`64`), and then dereference it so that single byte is read.

Your final  line is wrong, you meant:

```
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3, *emphasis mine*

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the
>   resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is
>   undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal to the
>   original pointer. **When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.** Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

So, the binary representation would look like [(*little-endian architecture assumed, based on output you presented*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian)

```
  00000001 01000000
    ^^         ^^
    HAB        LAB              HAB- High Address Byte, LAB - Low Address Byte
```

And, by the cast, you are essentially pointing to

```
           01000000
```

Part. So the dereference will produce that value as the integer result, `(01000000)`<sub>`2`</sub> == `(64)`<sub>`10`</sub>.

*Note: Only a character type pointer is capable of aliasing any other pointer type. Don;t try it with other target types which are not compatible with the source type.*

Comment: Note that this assumes little endian. Lowest addressed byte is not the same thing as least significant byte.

Comment: @Lundin added note.

Comment: @tilz0R Oops, I'm biased, I concur. :)

Comment: Detail: "Only `char *` is capable of aliasing any other type" --> Accessing though any character type is OK including `unsigned char, signed char`, and perhaps `uint8_t, int8_t`. C11 §6.5 7

Answer (score 1):

The different value is due to truncation; it also depends on the endian-ness of the platform  The value `640`, if stored in an `int` of say 16 byte, has the following binary pattern.

```
0000 0001 0100 0000
```

If a pointer to these two bytes is cast to a pointer of `char`, it will refer to the lower byte, which is as follows.

```
0100 0000
```

However, this bit pattern has a numerical value of `64`, which is the output of the program.